# Can $\exp\left(-i\frac{a}{b}\ln(2\cosh(bx))\right)$ be simplified further than $(e^{bx}+e^{-bx})^{-ia/b}$?

Tags: complex-analysis, algebra-precalculus, logarithms, hyperbolic-functions

Can the following expression be further simplified 
$$\exp\left(-i\frac{a}{b}\ln(2\cosh(bx))\right)$$
where $a$, $b$ are constant and $x$ is a variable?

I was able to do following simplification :

$$\begin{align}
\exp\left(\ln\left[(2\cosh(bx))^{-i \frac{a}{b}}\right]\right) &=(2\cosh(bx))^{-i \frac{a}{b}} \\
&=(e^{bx}+e^{-bx})^{-i \frac{a}{b}}
\end{align}$$

Comment: How about $e^{-iax}+e^{iax}=2\cos(ax)?$

Comment: @AdrianKeister Are you suggesting for binomial expansion? Cause $(a+b)^n \neq (a^n+b^n)$

Comment: No. I'm using the standard exponential-to-trig identity $\cos(x)=\dfrac{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}{2}.$

Comment: @AdrianKeister That I understand but this seems to not apply here unless I go for binomial expansion of cosh term

Comment: Ha! You're right. Fell prey to Freshman's Dream. Don't think you can do better than the $(2\cosh(bx))^{-ia/b}$ expression.

Answer (score 0):

Since $$\frac ab\log({2\cosh bx})$$ is always real, provided $a,b,x$ are real, then you can use the identity $$\exp(i\phi)=\cos\phi+i\sin\phi.$$ Afraid it wouldn't go further than that.